# How do I identify prior art on US20060272266A1 Modular Structure in the form of a question?

Tags: prior, art

I read this application ([US20060272266A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20060272266A1/en?oq=us20060272266A1)) on a modular structure that attempts to patent a well-known form of tension/compression structure. The application still seems open after all this time. I am new to this forum. This service is titled "Help us find prior art." Is my disclosure of prior art here relevant and timely?

Claim *1. A structure comprising:*

*a hub;*

*a plurality of elongated substantially rigid support members, each rigid support member having a distal end and a proximal end, the proximal end configured to contact an outer surface of the hub;*

*a plurality of elongated substantially flexible support members, each flexible support member configured to couple at least the distal ends of two of the rigid support members; and*

*wherein the flexible support members are in tension and the rigid support members are in compression to maintain the structure at equilibrium.*

R Buckminster Fuller's longstanding work is the quintessential prior art, including the Figure 730.12 and descriptive text [(See figure from Synergetics)](http://www.rwgrayprojects.com/synergetics/s07/figs/f3012.html), demonstrating a tetrahedron using, for example, a steel sphere as the hub. (Synergetics - Explorations in the Geometry of Thinking, R Buckminster Fuller in collaboration with EJ Applewhite, originally, Macmillan Publishing Co. Inc. 1975, 1979) He demonstrates how a stable structure can be developed by building and assembling these individual tensegrity units configured exactly as described and drawn in the application.

Another publication from the '70's also covers this: "an introduction to Tensegrity" Anthony Pugh, (c) 1976  Univ of California Press Berkeley ISBN 0-520-02996-8  describes this type of structure at Diagram 2.6/Figure 11.

Comment: If you link to the application it saves us effort tracking it down.

Answer (score 1):

This application went abandoned many years ago. You can look up the complete history of recent US patent applications at USPTO's Public PAIR web site. It allows access to all documents submitted by the applicant and issued by the patent office. This application was given a non-final rejection based upon [5014484 Tanizawa](http://patents.google.com/patent/US570857A).  Examiners do not necessarily look for a "quintessential" reference. They are prone to look first in US patents for something with all or most of the elements recited in the claims. Besides being easy for them to search for, patents include a description and most often drawings. They provide a "teaching" of the claimed device. As an aside, the applicant in this case informed the USPTO of a prior art umbrella patent from the 1800's and another in the early 1900's.

You mentioned that "it seems open after all these years". Patents and patent publications are fixed publications, like an issue of a magazine. If you look up a copy of Time magazine with JFK on its cover from 1960, it will not mention anything about his death.